# How to run SQL query automatically if SQL server DateTime matches with the column DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update STATUS column automatically only if StartDateTime (Table column value) and Server datetime match

Please help me resolve it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkiFS.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give more details on what you are trying to do. Please be aware that exact equality between a stored datestamp and a server `GETDATE()` value almost never occurs, because time matching to less than a second is very hard to achieve.

Comment: I think you need a chron job for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you question,

If it is in Query use Case Statement

If you want to update after insertion use Trigger

If you want to run automatically you can use jobs

Note:Exact Time match can never be achieved , at the most you should take the difference of both and if difference is not very huge(difference of couple of 40 to 50 sec) then you can conclude it is of same Timezone